# How to run custom script as screensaver in Openbox?

Tags: openbox, lxde, screensaver

I run Openbox/LXDE on a somewhat special platform (a Banana Pi Pro) which doesn't have DPMS support. I have to run specific commands to put my HDMI screen to standby and switch it back on. My scripts work nicely when called directly, and now I want to call them the same way a screensaver is called: one script (let's call it `screen_save`) is to be called after X minutes of inactivity and another script (`screen_restore`) is to be called on an input event, provided `screen_save` was called in between this input event and the previous one.

Do I have to write a daemon similar to `xscreensaver` which monitors the input and calls my scripts when necessary, or is there an existing screensaver daemon which could be configured to call my scripts? Or maybe there's a hook to `xorg`, `openbox` or `lxde` which I could use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [`xautolock`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xautolock) which can start a script after some idle time.

It is used like this

```
xautolock -time "$MINUTES" -locker "$SCRIPT"
```

It is supposed to be used with [`xlock`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xlock) which can lock the screen and starts a screensaver.

Since you need to deactivate the screen when the timeout is reached and reactivate it when you move the mouse or press any key. You could do something like this

```
screen_save
xlock -nolock -mode blank -mousemotion
screen_restore
```

The `xlock` process runs with a blank screen until the mouse is moved or a key is pressed and then it should reactivate your screen.

To start it for Openbox you can add

```
xautolock -time 10 -locker "screen_lock"&
```

to your `~/.config/openbox/autostart`. Don't forget the `&`.

Comment: This answer looks very promising, I will try it out this evening. The only thing I worry about is whether running `mplayer` will be considered as activity or not.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Why `mplayer`? You mean when you run `mplayer` if it stops `xautolock` from locking the screen? Good question I have not tried it. I only use it to lock my screen when I'm gone from my work computers.

Comment: FYI, your solution works fine, and playing a video with `mplayer` is considered as activity, so screen blanking doesn't get in the way. Note that I had to add `-noclose` option, otherwise my screensaver script doesn't get any `stdout` and fails to run some command-line utilities which output info on `stdout`.